# What source files should be included for Handlebars 4.0.2?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm just getting started with Handlebars.js and I'm already confused by what should be included in my HTML.

I set up a minimal helloworl HTML file that looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <div class="body">
        {{body}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
  var html    = template(context);
  document.write(html);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I get the following error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Handlebars.compile(source)')
global code (index.html, line 17)
```

What other dependency should be included for this minimal example to work?

Versions used:

- jQuery 2.1.4
- handlebars 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your call to `bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js` overwrites what `bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js` sets up.
2. Using `handlebars.runtime.js` implies that your templates are already compiled and thus the `Handlebars` object you get does not include a `compile` function.

Remove `<script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>`and you should be good to go : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dr3gwh7u/

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
    var html    = template(context);
    $('body').append(html)
</script>
```

Comment: Wow. It was actually really simple. Handlebar's installation instructions are super not clear: “handlebars.js and handlebars.runtime.js are the primary source files but a number of other options exist in this component.” (so I thought both were required)